Identifying whether a post is a shared post via Facebook Graph
I'm using Graph API Explorer to display our Facebook Page posts. The feed is producing everything I want but a couple of the posts are shared to our page.
The shared posts show the photos as an album but doesn't show any of the text, (message).  I'm assuming this may be due to permissions as it's a different page.
However I cannot find a way to identify in the feed whether a post is ours or one we have shared to our page.
Is there anyway of getting the text from the original page or at least identifying whether the post is one that s shared or not.
My graph call is quite lengthy at the moment until I establish what's needed.
me?fields=id,name,feed.limit(10){created_time,full_picture,id,message,message_tags,place,attachments.limit(100){description,description_tags,media,media_type,title,type,subattachments,target,unshimmed_url,url},status_type,via,sharedposts{description,from,message},to{name}},link,posts

EDIT:- I'm still struggling for a solution.
